# Javascript Alert box's conflicts with radiobuttonlist's selectedIndexChanged event

Tags: javascript, vb.net, alert, radiobuttonlist

I have created the called the `selectedIndexChange` event in button's click event. And after successfully execution of `selectedIndexChange` event javascript alert messege needed to be display.

Though the code is successfully executed, alert message is not being display. When I've tried by removing the `selectedIndexChange` event...IT WORKED! Pllease give me a way...

```
. '============buttonclick event
. 'some code
.
rblScreeningDate_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e)

Me.ObjCommon.ShowAlert("Record Saved Sucessfully", Me.Page) 'it is a javascript alert
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can call the selectedindexchanged event from inside a button click event?
The selectedindexchanged event belongs to the dropdown so passing an e argument belonging to a button is probably causing the issue.

I would recommend storing the selected index in a variable and checking if it has changed, if it has, then call a function say called ddlchanged() to handle it. Your selectedindexchanged function can call that same ddlchanged() function so you dont duplicate code.

Comment: Its' the radiobuttonlist's selectedIndexChanged, and yes, it is working. But what not working is the Alert message of the javascript that I've called through `objCommon.showAlert`.

I've even tried to show alert with `ScriptManager` but still its not working with `radioButtonList's selectedIndexChanged` event.